# What do these NULLS mean?

Tags: php, sql-server-2000, sqlsrv

From this page over at Microsoft; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc626305.aspx, they give examples on how to use paramaterized queries by showing how to properly build an array.  Here is a snippet of sample code:

```
$params1 = array(
               array($employeeId, null),
               array($changeDate, null, null, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_DATETIME),
               array($rate, null, null, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_MONEY),
               array($payFrequency, null, null, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_TINYINT)
           );
```

I understand the variables and the constants, but they fail to explain what the nulls are for.  Sometimes they are used, sometimes they aren't and sometimes there are two;

```
variable, null, null, constant
```

Can someone explain this to me, or point me to the right place?  I can't find any reading material about this.

Thank you.

Comment: When something expects something else to be passed, and you have nothing to pass, you pass NULL instead ?

Comment: i think the question is why are there differing numbers of params between arrays. that i don't know - probably has something to do with sql server.

Comment: oh there you go - at the top of the page: "For details about the structure and syntax of the $params array, see sqlsrv_query or sqlsrv_prepare."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is akin to invoking an overloaded function.  Sometimes the function takes 2 parameters:

```
       array($employeeId, null)
```

sometimes it is 4:

```
           array($rate, null, null, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_MONEY)
```

Placing null in these function calls generally means no value.  If you look at the different queries/functions that get invoked from these you will most likely see that the parameters are used in different ways.  Further a null passed into the function implies that it would be an optional parameter, which is why it comes in as no value or null.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer.  As @sgroves mentions above, I visited the link at the top of the page, bringing me here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296184.aspx.  It looks as though those extra spots are used to tell the driver which way the variables are going... this still doesn't make sense to me, however.  If you can explain this and edit your answer, I will certainly accept it.  Thanks for your time!